# Connect to remote H2 Database in intellj idea

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, database-connection, h2

I have an application running on a server and I'm using H2 database for that,

This my database URL:

`jdbc:h2:./cafeDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=7080`

And I want to connect to this database using Intellj idea's database tools, this is my configuration:

[image: Database configuration]

But when I try to connect, It keeps asking me the DB's username and password, and even when I put the correct information and submit it says:

The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [28000][28000] Wrong user name or password [28000-200]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First of all, check the official [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connectivity-problems.html) that describes how to solve the common database connection issues. If the issue remains please raise a new issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and attach a compressed [log folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) for the investigation.